# Why my custom Nextjs server doesn't work in my Vercel deployment?

Tags: next.js, vercel

Hi I have this repository for testing. In localhost I can see when I execute "npm run dev" my custom server.... server.js at root makes the redirection if exists my custom cookie.
But In production in Vercel I cannot see this custom server is working (I can see because in Server.js I add a Session Cookie with name "n-session" with value "1", but in production not working (also the logs in Server.js don't display this traces in Server.js).

In my package.json I can see:

```
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "node server.js",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
        "export": "next export",
      },
```

My server.js has this code:

```
    // server.js
    const { createServer } = require('http')
    const { parse } = require('url')
    const next = require('next')
    
    const app = next({})
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
    
    var Cookies = require('cookies');
    
    const { localeLanguages } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;
    
    app.prepare().then(() => {
      createServer((req, res) => {
        // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
        // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
        const { pathname } = parsedUrl;
    
        console.log("pathname", pathname)
        if (pathname === '/') {
          console.log("pathname is root..................")
          const mainLang = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAIN_LANG;  
    
          let uriRedirect = null;
    
          if (req && req.headers) 
          {
            console.log("req.headers", req.headers)
            const cookies = new Cookies(req, res);
        
            let userLang = mainLang;  
            let userLangCookie = cookies.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_LANGUAGE_COOKIE);
            let initSession = cookies.get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INIT_SESION_COOKIE);
            
            console.log("userLangCookie", userLangCookie)
            console.log("initSession", initSession)
    
            let acceptLanguage = req.headers['accept-language']; 
            if (acceptLanguage) {  
              acceptLanguage = (acceptLanguage.split(',')[0]).split('-')[0];
    
              let found = localeLanguages.filter(function (e) {
                return e.label == acceptLanguage;
              });
              if (found.length > 0) {
                userLang = acceptLanguage;
              }
    
              if (typeof initSession === "undefined" || initSession === null)
              {
                if (typeof userLangCookie === "undefined" || 
                  userLangCookie === null && userLang !== mainLang) 
                {
                  uriRedirect = `/${userLang}`;
                }
                else if (userLangCookie !== mainLang)
                {
                  uriRedirect = `/${userLangCookie}`;
                }
                cookies.set(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INIT_SESION_COOKIE, 1, {
                  httpOnly: true // true by default
                })
              }
            } 
          }
          console.log("uriRedirect", uriRedirect)
          
          if (uriRedirect !== null) { 
              res.writeHead(302, { Location: `${uriRedirect}` }).end(); 
          } else {
            handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
          }
        } else {
          handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
        }
      }).listen(3000, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err
        console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
      })
    })
```

I upload to Vercel using my github repository with git commands add/commit/push

My repository is this: https://github.com/anialamo/nootric-next10

Can you help me please? What is wrong in my deploy?

Where should my server.js file be hosted? also in Vercel?
A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Before using a custom server, you must read the doc to see the disadvantages

it states this:

"A custom server can not be deployed on Vercel, the platform Next.js was made for.

Before deciding to use a custom server please keep in mind that it should only be used when the integrated router of Next.js can't meet your app requirements. A custom server will remove important performance optimizations, like serverless functions and Automatic Static Optimization."

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

Comment: Ok! thanks! Do you know just in case..How can I make a redirection from my Index page if I uses Static Html with StaticProps but I need in my IndexPage e.g. I used ServerSideProps and this works fine! But when I execute https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ to make a crawling for my website. I am using also i18n for Nextjs 10... when I crawl my website in my secondary language the crawler dont gives me the crawling results are wrong. For this reason in my localhost I use a custom server.js, because getServerSideProps does not allow me to have a static site that works properly for crawlers. Any ideas?