# Next.js with express server not working in production

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, vercel

I want to learn how to deploy my next.js app that has an express server side. In development everything works fine but in production I cannot get the app to work at all! Below is my ./server/index.js. I have followed multiple guides but they all lead into an error. I'm sure it is something I am overlooking something simple.

```
const express = require('express');
 const next = require('next');
path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const passport = require('passport')
const flash = require('express-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { setPassport, checkAuthenticated, checkNotAuthenticated,registerAdmin } = 
require('./PassPortLocale');
const {createAccount} = require('../utils/mongo/createAccount');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const Server = next({ dev });
const handle = Server.getRequestHandler();

Server.prepare().then(() => {

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const dbURI;

mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => { console.log("connected to database"); });
const MS = require('express-mongoose-store')(session,mongoose);
app.use(flash());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'guild',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MS({ttl:60000})
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
setPassport(passport);


app.use(methodOverride('_method'))


const auth = require('./routes/auth');

app.use('/login', auth)

app.get('/about', checkAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
    return Server.render(req, res,'/about')
})

app.get('/register',checkNotAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
    return Server.render(req,res,'/register')
})

app.post('/register', checkNotAuthenticated, async (req,res)=>{
    let {username, password, email} = req.body
    
    const register =  await registerAdmin(username, password);
    
    res.status(200).json({'success':'user has been added!'})
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
});


app.listen(4000, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.info(`> Ready on http://localhost:${4000}`);
});




});

 module.exports = {Server}
```

And here is my package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "node ./server/server.js",
"build": "next build",
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./server/server.js",
"lint": "next lint"
```

Any help will do. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you are trying to deploy to Vercel, what errors did you encounter? Have you read the related documentation? https://vercel.com/guides/using-express-with-vercel

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why my custom Nextjs server doesn't work in my Vercel deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289652/why-my-custom-nextjs-server-doesnt-work-in-my-vercel-deployment)? Vercel does not support Next.js apps with a custom server implementation. See https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/overview#supported-next.js-features.